# How to add new elements each loop in a set of tuples?

Tags: python, set, tuples, list-comprehension, slice

I need help with converting a string of tuple into a set of tuples using comprehension and slicing preferably. I just cannot figure out how to add new elements each time.

Input: ('test', 'sample', 'check')

Expected: {('test',),('test','sample',),('test', 'sample', 'check')}

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: What's a `string of tuple` ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work:

```
x = ('test', 'sample', 'check')

set_of_tuples = {x[:i+1] for i in range(len(x))}

print(set_of_tuples)
```

Result is:

```
{('test',), ('test', 'sample'), ('test', 'sample', 'check')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using set comprehension:

```
{s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s))}
# {('test',), ('test', 'sample'), ('test', 'sample', 'check')}
```